# Can I create a website project type in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web, project

We're upgrading to VS2010 and when I look in my "new project" window I can only see web application, not website. Has this gone? Is there an alternative?

I need this project type because we need to be able to edit code files on the fly on the live server - or has this now become an option embedded somewhere in the application project.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use File>New>New Web Site, and you can find the web site templates.

But it does look like a very bad idea to edit on the fly files on a live server... Unless your customers are very understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is the answer since I ran into a similar thing with Visual Studio 2008, but I thought maybe it's still a quirk in Visual Studio 2010.  I posted this on the "Community Content" section in the MSDN pages.

**Creating multi-project solutions**

This workflow to create a multi-project solution seems simple (and is), but it is very confusing if doing it for the first time, because this workflow wasn't QA'ed very well for intuativeness.

File > New > Project > New Project
... both the menu option and the dialog are misleading.. they should both say Project/Solution.. just like the Open menu does

Expand "Other Project Types", choose "Visual Studio Solutions" > Blank Solution

Right click your solution in Solution Explorer > Add New Project >
... I chose Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application (for an example)

OH NO!  The solution dissapeared!

No problem, go to Tools (menu) > Options > Projects and Solutions > choose "Always show solution"
... sadly, this is unchecked by default for Visual Studio 2008